# Convert many raw strings to Pathlib Path

Tags: python, path, pathlib

So I have many raw strings to different files, and I'd like my script to automatically convert them to Path's using Pathlib. The obvious solution is:

```
from Pathlib import Path

path1 = r'/path/to/my/file1'
path2 = r'/path/to/my/file2'

path1 = Path(path1)
path2 = Path(path2)
```

But this becomes quite unreadable once there are many different paths involved. I was thinking about putting the variables in a list, and then loop over this list and converting them. Something like this:

```
path_list = [path1, path2]

for raw_path in path_list:
   variable = Path(raw_path)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as *variable* in the code above needs to be *path1* in the 1st iteration and *path2* in the 2nd iteration.

Do you have any tips how to solve this in the most Pythonic way?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a **list** of paths, you should deal with them all at once inside a Python `list`:

```py
raw_path_list = [path1, path2]

path_list = [Path(raw_path) for raw_path in raw_path_list]

# access path1
path_list[0]
```

If you actually need the `path1` terminology to hold, use a `dict` instead:

```py
path_list = {f'path{i}':Path(raw_path) for i, raw_path in enumerate(raw_path_list)}

# access path1
path_list['path1']
```